# replace the unknown value using php

Tags: php, replace

In my project am using some post, in that post i got  a error in browser like this,

"fourth � one - hai" => i paste that error, but i cant get in, Its like a square between fourth and one... But i dont know that issue, and also  i cant string replace that value, and i try to attach the screenshot, that also not working...

And if u want to see that symbol please inspect the space between fourth and one...  Help me..

Comment: please give me any suggestions.....

Comment: Seems to be an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with your question but check the PHP manual.

http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php